# Append values of other records for a distinct values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

if my database table is like:

```
  name    col_2
 Manish  352-103
 Manish  342-123
 ganesh  362-111
 ganesh  789-232
 abcd    456-231
 abcd    047-234
```

now i want it as:

> ```
>   name      col-2
>  Manish  352-103, 342-123
>  ganesh  362-111, 789-232
>  abcd    456-231, 047-234
> ```

(I need distinct values of name and  col-2 values must appended for the each distinct value of name)
Both column values are of type text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the requirement in MySQL

`select name, group_concat(col-2) from dbo.sample group by name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select name, string_agg(concat(col-2, ', '))
    from dbo.Sample 
    group by name
```

Comment: SQL Error [1305] [42000]: FUNCTION db_name.string_agg does not exist